# Drop file onto batch file to write that filename into the batch file's script?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Let's say I have a batchfile named batch.bat with contents like:

```
@echo off

C:\path\to\program\program.exe -variables "%1"
```

and let's say I have a file called file.txt
and a second file called file2.txt

and let's say I drop file.txt onto batch.bat.

What I want to happen is:

- file.txt opens with program.exe
- ***and*** batch.bat's contents get overwritten to now say something like:

```
    @echo off

    C:\path\to\program\program.exe -variables "file.txt"
```

- Now if I double-click on batch.bat, it will open file.txt with program.exe
- It will continue to do this on double-click, until I drop file2.txt onto batch.bat. At that point, batch.bat's contents will be overwritten again to be:

```
     @echo off

     C:\path\to\program\program.exe -variables "file2.txt"
```

Is this concept possible? What would the batch file contents need to be?

If this can be accomplished in some other simple way, I'm open to that too. But I need to be able to run a command-line command with arguments, because I'm running a command-line program, not notepad or what-not.

Comment: Yes, it is very possible.  I myself would put your "variables" into a separate file.  Don't try to mess with your live batch.   I will give you some hints.. 1)  If NOT "%~1"=="" then write the variable to an external file. 2)  read the external file to get your variable.  Error if empty.  Call your program.exe with the variable.

Comment: Thank you @SeñorCMasMas. With your hint, I've figured out a solution and posted an answer.

Comment: Is it correct to rephrase it as you want `batch.bat` to launch your program with the dropped-to filename as argument, or with the last used filename as argument when clicked?

Comment: Yes, that's a correct way to rephrase it

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method that doesn't require multiple files and is very simple. While it does not recreate the batch, I think it works in a superior manner.

```
@echo off
REM Must be run as  administrator
REM Get the value passed in if any
SET var=%1

REM If a value was passed in, save the value to a system environment variable
if not "%var%"=="" SETX MinJarLastFile %var% -m

REM If nothing was passed in restore from the environment variable
if "%var%"=="" SET var=%MinJarLastFile%

REM Run application with variable
"C:\path\to\program\program.exe" -variables "%var%"

REM Exit
exit /B /0
```

Comment: This looks like a very elegant solution. It's not quite working for me so I think there may be something wrong somewhere, maybe just some missing quote marks or something simple like that. For testing purposes, I've made the executable "notepad.exe" (in quotes) and removed "-variables" but it doesn't work when I drop a text file onto the batch file.

Comment: @loopernow I just tested with the line "C:\Windows\Notepad.exe" "%var%" and it worked perfectly fine for me. If you see errors saving the value, that is because it is not running with administrator privileges.

Comment: I gotcha. It seems to be an issue with the file I was testing it with. Dropping other files works fine. A different issue, though, is the Administrator rights requirement. I looked it up online and I can create a shortcut to the batch and give that shortcut administrator rights. But Windows shows the UAC box every time I use the shortcut, and I'm not comfortable changing the security level for my entire Windows account just for this. So this seems to be a niche solution--but elegant!

Answer (score 0):

With @SeñorCMasMas's help, I've come up with a solution using the *if*, *set*, *echo* (to a file), and *start* commands.

The *start* command requires a title argument if the path or file you're opening has spaces in it. In addition, it needs a separate path argument and filename argument if this is the case. So, my batch file is considerably longer to allow for these possibilities.

```
if not "%~1"=="" set input-title=""
if not "%~1"=="" set input-path="%~dp1"
if not "%~1"=="" set input-file="%~nx1"
if not "%~1"=="" echo %input-title% /d %input-path% %input-file%>input.txt
set /p start-input=<input.txt
start %start-input%
```

https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html was useful for explaining that arguments passed to a batch file are represented differently than other variables--with only a leading "%", no trailing "%".

[The Windows documentation for 'for'](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490909(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) was useful for explaining variable substitution, which allows you to break down a drive+path+file variable into its component parts, and which allows you to remove enclosing double quotes from an argument value by using "~".

Comment: Not necessary to repeat `if not "%~1"` ... You can build code blocks. `if not "%~1"=="" ( cmd1 <newline> cmd2 <newline> cmd3 ... )`

Comment: Thank you @jeb. That makes sense!

Comment: Nice one @loopernow!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need a bat file, to be able to read/write automatically, according to your own content or to the passing of arguments (drag & drop file).

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && cd /d "%~dp0"

if not "%~1" == "" %__APPDIR__%mode.com 40,3 & goto :set_cmd:
type "%~f0"|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /b \^; >nul && goto :run_cmd:
goto :error:

:set_cmd:
set "_run="C:\Windows\system32\where.exe" /r "%cd%" "%~nx1" "

( type "%~f0"|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /bv \^; & echo/^;!_run!
  rem./See the results in your test & echo/;"%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe" -1
  echo/;endlocal ^&^& goto :EOF ) >"%tmp%\tmp_%~nx0" 

>nul copy /y "%tmp%\tmp_%~nx0" "%~nx0" & endlocal && goto :EOF

:error:
cls & echo= & echo= & endlocal 
echo\ Sorry %username%, no valid argumment was passed^!! 
echo= & echo\ For set command: & echo=
echo\       By Command Line^> %~nx0 "Input_File_.ext"
echo\       By Windows use Drag ^& Drop "input_file_.ext" %~nx0
%__APPDIR__%timeout -1 & goto :EOF

:run_cmd:
echo/ your code will enter/executed bellow here...
```

If you just click on this file **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)** for 1st time without drag and drop any file, or run it from the command line without an argument, you will get these results:

```bat
 Sorry /UserVarName/, no valid argumment was passed!!

 For set command:

       By Command Line> Q1528263v2.cmd "Input_File_.ext"
       By Windows use Drag & Drop "input_file_.ext" Q1528263v2.cmd

Press any key to continue ...
```

The same will happened if you remove the lines starting with **"`;`"**, this action will "reset" to original stats...

But, for any file you drag and drop, it will be saved as an argument in your execute command variable **`_run`** (it's a replacement/overwrite action).

---

[image]

---

**Obs.:** Just replace:

```bat
set "_run="C:\Windows\system32\where.exe" /r "%cd%" "%~nx1" "
```

```bat
set "_run="C:\path\to\program\program.exe" -variables  "%~1" "
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to confirm the path each launch, use the following:
`<input.txt (Set /P "input=")`

You can also achieve this with only the one variable, and have a more robust status check like so:

```
@ECHO off
    If not "%~1"=="" (
            Set "input=%~1"
        ) Else (
        If exist "input.txt" (
                 <"input.txt" (Set /P "input=")
            ) Else (
            Set /p "input=Path:<"
        )
    )
    For %%A in ("%input%") Do (
        ECHO(%%~A>"input.txt"
        Start "" /d "%%~dpA" "%%~nxA"
    )
    pause
```