# Combining batch files so double click performs one operation and the next double click reverses or performs the next operation?

Tags: batch, netsh

So I have two separate batch files. One to disable the NIC and enable the wifi card:

```
@netsh interface set interface name="Ethernet" admin=disabled
@netsh interface set interface name="Wi-Fi" admin=Enabled
```

and another to do the opposite (enable the NIC and disable the wifi card):

```
@netsh interface set interface name="Wi-Fi" admin=disabled
@netsh interface set interface name="Ethernet" admin=Enabled
```

How do I combine them into one batch that I can double click to toggle one way and double click again to toggle the other way?

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Batch files don't know about mouse clicks when they are executed.

Comment: You could probably write a batch file that detects whether something is enable/disabled and then do the required action ...

Comment: `netsh interface show interface` shows Admin State as Enabled or Disable. You can parse this output ...

Comment: I believe OP is trying to figure out how to combine the scripts and, after testing for the current state of each, take the appropriate action. The double-clicking is simply the running of the single batch file, which would presumably be called something like "Toggle connectivity"

Comment: @FlexYourData Indeed, I didn't have time yesterday to write a full answer so I gave some hints. Now I've answered :)

Comment: @DavidPostill
I copied the commands to a file and saved as a .bat, but running it as admin or without admin doesn't do anything.  Do I need to change interface names in the command?

Comment: If yours are named something else then yes.  I used the names from your question.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok so mine are named what I had in my original batch above (Ethernet and Wi-Fi).  I can't get it to work though.  When I run it, nothing happens.  I've tried running it as admin also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

---

I've already answered a similar question, and by looking for something "better" than my own answer, I've offered an bounty at that time.

What came to deserve it was a *[@UnhandledExcepSean](https://superuser.com/users/370151/unhandledexcepsean)*  *[**`answer`**](https://superuser.com/a/1530603/969781)*, it comes down to using a value in the register, where in your case, reading and writing to then "perceive" the relevant on/off actions...

```bath
@echo off & setlocal

pushd %__AppDir__% && 2>nul =;(
    reg.exe query HKCU\Environment /d /e /f on|find.exe /i "Click" >nul && =;(
    netsh.exe interface set interface name="Ethernet" admin=Disabled
    netsh.exe interface set interface name="Wi-Fi" admin=Enabled 
    setx.exe Click off >nul & endlocal & goto :eof                  );= || =;( 
    netsh.exe interface set interface name="Ethernet" admin=Enabled
    netsh.exe interface set interface name="Wi-Fi" admin=Disabled 
    setx.exe Click on 1>nul & endlocal & goto :eof                  );= );=
```

---

- One alternative:

```bath
@echo off

setlocal & pushd %__AppDir__% && 2>nul =;(
    reg.exe query HKCU\Environment /d /e /f on|find.exe /i "Click" >nul && =;(
    set "_Eth=Disable" && set "_Wi-Fi=Enabled" && set "_click=off" ) || =;(
    set "_Eth=Enabled" && set "_Wi-Fi=Disable" && set "_click=on"  ) );=    

netsh.exe interface set interface name="Ethernet" admin=%_Eth%
netsh.exe interface set interface name="Wi-Fi" admin=%_Wi-Fi%
setx.exe Click %_Click% 1>nul & popd & endlocal & exit /b
```

Comment: Tried both and they both work!  Thanks as well.

Comment: @darien.day With more time I will add explanatory content

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I combine them into one batch file?

`netsh interface show interface` shows `Admin State` as `Enabled` or `Disabled` for the interfaces.

The following batch file parses the output of the above command and toggles the state of the two connections.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem run netsh and get admin status and interface name
rem skip headers
for /f "tokens=1,4* skip=3" %%f in ('netsh interface show interface') do (
  set _admin=%%f
  set _interface=%%g %%h
  if "!_interface!" == "Wi-Fi" (
    if "!_admin!" == "Enabled" (
      netsh interface set interface name="!_interface!" admin=disabled
      ) else (
      netsh interface set interface name="!_interface!" admin=enabled
      )
    )
  if "!_interface!" == "Ethernet" (
    echo !_interface!
    if "!_admin!" == "Enabled" (
      netsh interface set interface name="!_interface!" admin=disabled
      ) else (
      netsh interface set interface name="!_interface!" admin=enabled
      )
    )
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [For /f - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Netsh - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html)
- [Netsh commands for Interface IP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx)
- [Netsh Commands for Wireless Local Area Network (WLAN)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)